# How to solve a datasource error in Microsoft report viewer?

Tags: c#, sql, windows, rdlc

i am having Report page in my windows project .In that i included *microsoftReportViewer* . In that page two combobox is there .items in 1st combobox are:

1. FirmDetails
2. ChittyHolding
3. LoanDetails.

Corresponding to selection this items in combobox1, items in combobox will change .I need report According to this values in 2 combbox.

My code is like

```
if (cbReprt.Text == "FirmDetails")
        {

            if (cbGeneral.Text == "AllFirmDetails")
            {
                reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=202.88.231.102;Initial Catalog=dbs_Merchant;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=abc123*");
                con.Open();
                allfirmdetails ds = new allfirmdetails();
                string str = "Select * from View_2";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(ds);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local;
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "F:\\MerchantAssociation\\MerchantAssociation\\Report7.rdlc";
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("allfirmdetails_View_2", dt));
                reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            }


            else
            {
                reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=202.88.231.102;Initial Catalog=dbs_Merchant;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=abc123*");
                con.Open();
                allfirmdetails ds1 = new allfirmdetails();
                string str1 = "Select * from View_2 where FirmName='" + cbGeneral.Text + "'";
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(str1, con);
                SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
                da1.Fill(ds1);
                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                da1.Fill(dt1);
                reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local;
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "F:\\MerchantAssociation\\MerchantAssociation\\firmwise.rdlc";
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("allfirmdetails_View_2", dt1));
                reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

            }
        }
        else if (cbReprt.Text == "ChittyDetails")
        {
            if (cbGeneral.Text == "AllChittyDetails")
            {
                reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=202.88.231.102;Initial Catalog=dbs_Merchant;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=abc123*");
                con.Open();
                ChittyDetails ds2 = new ChittyDetails();
                string str2 = "Select * from View_1";
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(str2, con);
                SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
                da2.Fill(ds2);
                DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
                da2.Fill(dt2);
                reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local;
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "F:\\MerchantAssociation\\MerchantAssociation\\allchitty.rdlc";
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("ChittyDetails_View_1", dt2));
                reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            }
```

First I select chittyholding details. Then I got the report. Then I select chitty details report, I got the error like
`**An error occured during local report processing .A data sourcr instance has not been supplied for the data source "ChittyHolding_View_7"**`. If I close and run the project again ,then that firmdetails selection will work.But another will not work.It means Only for one selection I am getting the report. Why? Please solve this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call `reportViewer1.Reset();` instead of `reportViewer1.Refresh();` at the beginning of every condition